# Configurable and custom options problems in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

I'm having problems with Configurable and custom options, the simple products works fine and it shows the add to cart button, but with Configurable and custom options it disappears and the drop down options doesn't work.
Can anyone help me?

eg https://floty.com/sinalizador-nado-costas-metro-linear.html 
as you can see, there is no add to cart button nor the dropdown options works

Answer (score 1):

The product page you have posted has lot of Javascript errors... fix them & the dropdown should work

[image]

You can start by disabling JS merge. In some cases, that only action will fix the problem... if not, you should study the order of the JS resources in head, to check if **jQuery** is being correctly loaded, without causing conflicts with other libraries such **Prototype**

Comment: Can i get help about custom option not working, https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/266640/57334. If run my live code into my localhost its working. @Raul Sanchez

Comment: In my case, it was `OrganicInternet_SimpleConfigurableProducts` module which doesn't work with Magento 1.9.3.4+