# Magento 1.9.2.3 Product Custom Options - Filters Not Working - Prototype.js error

Tags: custom-options, product-page, prototype-js, magento1.9.2.3

I cant able to use Custom Options, drop-down showing error in prototype.js:612

[image]

and my prototype.js:

https://justpaste.it/61c3a

Comment: i have checked your prototype.js and js is good you have any custom coding or js added?

Comment: @RakeshDonga Actually the project maintained by couple of peoples, so is any way i can find what is the issue?

Comment: check any js code your admin side

Comment: @RakeshDonga Yes i need to manually test all the Js file under public_html/js folder, is any quick way can i sort out the error?

Comment: @RakeshDonga If i run my live code into localhost its working, actually now i backup my code and run in my localhost its working.

Comment: but you can check which change in previous developer because some mistake create in coding then not working i think

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91298/discussion-between-zus-and-rakesh-donga).